# EntityFramework OData Spatial Geography - POST returns error (no parameterless constructor)

Tags: entity-framework, odata, spatial

I am trying to create an OData service for an entity with a System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography type property. The entity is part of EntityFramework context (database). Getting the data in/out of the Db works fine. I am able to request the data from OData service. It is returned as a WKT string. However, when I POST a similar entity back to insert a new record into the Db, I get the error "no parameterless constructor" from the framework. It is the DbGeography constructor referred I guess, because when the property is set to null in the POST request, all is fine.

I found that OData should be working better with System.Spatial.Geography (I used System.Spatial.GeographyPoint). Even then it complaints about the IConvertible interface not implemented when I post data.

Is there any "direct" way of getting the data out and into the OData service using the Entity.DbGeography (and similar) types? I found some ways of binding in case of using MVC models and controllers - would similar action be needed here? Or should I "just" use the System.Spatial.Geography for OData and translate to DbGeography for EF? Something like:

```
Geography --> OData service --> .net translate --> DbGeography --> EF --> DB
```

I found another question similar to this one: [OData + EF. Writing geography types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23580892/odata-ef-writing-geography-types)
But there is no answers nor comments there at all. I assume this problem may have some trivial solution I cannot see, or no one has the same issue (hard to believe...)?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Comment: At the end I decided to store coordinated of a point in two Double fields. The reason was that the "automatic" conversion did not work. I had to make the system working. When things improve, I may change it.